# Android Canvas, multiple paths with different zoom amounts

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing, zooming

It's supposed to be a simple whiteboard kind of tool, with zoom/panning effects.

Everything is alright with the entire drawing of the paths part, except for when it comes down to zooming/panning.

When a zoom is applied to the whiteboard, no matter the way I do, all the lines that come after the zoom applied get displaced in respect with the position I actually did the stroking.

I'll try to expose the details as good as it's possible, without showing unnecessary code, still it's quite a long post, please, bear with me.

As an image is worth a thousand words, I will illustrate the situation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, I've tried many different approaches, without any success.

Now down to the technical part, this is what I'm doing right now:

It's implemented extending the View.

I use the onDraw method only to perform the 'animation' of the strokes being applied:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(isDrawing)
    {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);   
    }
}
```

I have two ImageViews that I use to place the resulting bitmap right after the drawing and zooming are performed. The reason I use two views is to swap them in order to always have one available view at the drawing rendering moment.

```
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
 android:visibility="visible"     
 android:scaleType="matrix" />

 <ImageView     
 android:id="@+id/imageView2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"          
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
 android:visibility="visible"     
 android:scaleType="matrix" />
```

After something is drawn to the canvas, I send the given bitmap to my view, then clean the canvas to set it brand new to more drawings:

```
 private void sendImage2BackView()
 {
     //veeery extensive and boring code surpressed here

     //set the entire hocus-pocus' resulting bitmap as a resource for my view
     mView.setImageBitmap(tempBmp);
     mView.bringToFront();  


 }
```

I implement a ScaleListener class that extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener

During the onScale moments, I tell my canvas what my scalling proportion is:

```
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) 
{   
    drawAction = ZOOM;      
    scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
    scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));

    canvas.setScaleFactor(scaleFactor);
    return true;
}
```

Then, at my View ( canvas obj ), I just set the scale to the view being used:

```
    mView.setScaleX(factor);
    mView.setScaleY(factor);
```

Now, for the most important part, at the onScaleEnd, I call a method which I attempt to get the current canvas bitmap AS IS and send it to my view to abide peacefully with its siblings, each one its own size and offset.

```
    public void setScaleEnd()
    {
         //Lots of more boring code surpressed here
         //....

         //I store the bitmap that was contained at the ImageView
         // IF anyone is present
         previousBmp = ((BitmapDrawable)mView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

         //then, I create a brand new scaled bitmap,in order to 
         // acquire the same proportion of ZOOM that I've just applied
         tempBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(previousBmp,
            (int)(mView.getWidth()*scaleFactor),
            (int)(mView.getHeight()*scaleFactor), true);


         int height = (int)(mView.getHeight()*scaleFactor);
         int width = (int)(mView.getWidth()*scaleFactor);

         //set my matrix
         mMatrix = new Matrix();

         //give it the right proportion
         mMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

         translationX = mView.getWidth() / 2 - width / 2;
         translationY = mView.getHeight() / 2 - height / 2;

         //give it some necessary translation amount
         mMatrix.postTranslate(translationX, translationY);

         //set the matrix to the view, and send the resized bitmap to my ImageView.
         mView.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
         mView.setImageBitmap(tempBmp);
    }
```

Now, I have tried during everything I just showed straight to the canvas, giving it a scale/translate amount; tried working separately with bitmaps then sent them back to a new clean canvas.

Still I keep getting that displacement on my strokes after a given amount of ZOOM is applied!!!
I just want to be able to draw; give it a zoom; then draw some more things, and have the strokes stay where I'm drawing!

Is that possible?

I was just playing with S Note app, it does exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Don't know how I can help, but this's the most detailed question I ever seen on StackOverflow, congrats!

Comment: I've gone that path and would recommend you use a good vector rendering library. Android paths implementation is horribly slow in rendering and is not smooth curved at large dimensions (zoom). Look for a good openvg implementation.

Comment: @S.D. That's something I have in mind, gotta perfect the paths when in zoom. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I want to propose some solution to you, but I'm not sure it will works.

At first I need to clarify, that you've done a big mistake in this code:

```
     tempBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(previousBmp,
        (int)(mView.getWidth()*scaleFactor),
        (int)(mView.getHeight()*scaleFactor), true);
```

Let's assume that you have a tablet with `1280x800` pixels and scale factor `4x` or even `10x`. You will try to allocate `16Mb` and `40Mb` Bitmap accordingly!

It's so easy to get `OutOfMemoryError` thrown here, so you need to use conceptually another approach.

I advice you to use [`Picture`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html) class.

1. You need to determine which size of **original** picture do you provide to the user?
2. After that you need to create the `Canvas` object around your picture using method [`Picture.beginRecord(int width, int height)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html#beginRecording%28int,%20int%29)
3. Now you can apply scale factor, translate the canvas and perform drawing operations.
4. Inside the `onDraw()` method you need to draw your picture using method [`Picture.draw(Canvas canvas)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) with corresponding settings (scale factor, translate) applied to canvas.

I didn't try this solution, but I hope that the `Picture` class will help you.

Comment: Hey @Olekssi Kropachov, thanks a lot for the help. I'm going to try it, and then I'll tell you if it works. 
I wasn't acquainted with that Picture class, seems legit!

And thanks for the advice on the image resizing!

Comment: Hey @Oleksii Kropachov, 

I tried using the Picture object, it seems pretty cool the way it is supposed to work. But, unfortunatelly, it didn't work at all.

Besides not being hardware accelerated at all, I couldn't even make it draw anything, let alone apply zooming, and panning matrix.

Comment: Just so you can follow my development, I put this straight down in my onDraw method:

     Picture picture = new Picture();
     Canvas cnv = picture.beginRecording(_w, _h);
     
     cnv.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
     cnv.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
     cnv.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0,  0, mPaint);
     
     picture.draw(cnv);
     mCanvas.drawPicture(picture);
     picture.endRecording();

And it didn't even set my strokes on screen.
While if I draw directly onto my canvas, it goes everything fine 

        canvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint); 
     canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);

Comment: you need to create `Picture` object outside of `onDraw()` method; if it's possible - just publish your sources on github and I'll try to help you with code

Comment: I first tried creating Picture outside the onDraw() method. It is currently there just for simplicity's sake, as this code is only a prototype attempt. 

Here ya go: https://github.com/cfernandomaciel/zoomCanvasPrototype.git

Comment: Are you able to upload the code in a way that we are able to run in our devices?, maybe I am asking too much, but would be great to try it, thank you...

Comment: @ClaudioFernandoMaciel I faced a similar problem, You have two states, when the user draw, and when the user scales. you need to detect when the user is going to draw, before bringing the view to the front and do something like drawView.translate(translationX, translationY).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, as for the zoom part, we had to put that to a future development. @agusgambina that was exactly what I had in mind, I'm certainly going to give it a try! As soon as I have it, I'll post the results here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @agusgambina here is the code:
https://github.com/cfernandomaciel/zoomCanvasPrototype